# is is possible to create a graph like below using thirdparty libraries like mpchartengine in Android

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have requirement to create a line graph with multicolored entrypoints and i have attached the screeshot.Please provide the help on this.

[image: Graph]

Comment: 1) like below? no image... 2) you should probably google and do some research on this before coming here and asking us. the short answer is yes, the long answer is google.com

Comment: Yeah this is possible.

Comment: @DroidDev i have already tried but struckup

Comment: #zunjae please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and also need a little bit customization